# jboss started but error in web service

Tags: java, web-services, jboss

I have started the jboss but I get the below error while accessing the web services. This occurs sometimes. What could be the problem? Is it that some jar are missing? if yes, how is it possible that sometimes it does not find some jar files? Pleaes guide. The two urls of web services are "https://203.77.203.196:8447/GetGPRSMtrBillService/services/GetGPRSConBillDataSoapPort"  and
"https://203.77.203.196:8447/EPaymentWebService/services/NotifyInstaPaymentSoapPort"

### exception

"javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet AxisServlet threw exception
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:828)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:601)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)"

### root cause

"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axis/SimpleChain
    org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDChain.makeNewInstance(WSDDChain.java:121)
    org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDTargetedChain.makeNewInstance(WSDDTargetedChain.java:151)
    org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getTransport(WSDDDeployment.java:410)
    org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getTransport(FileProvider.java:257)
    org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getTransport(AxisEngine.java:332)
    org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.initQueryStringHandlers(AxisServlet.java:1057)
    org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:200)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:828)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:601)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axis/SimpleChain
```

It seems you have wrong version of axis jars in your classpath. Make sure you have valid jars in classpath.

Comment: Nambari -  I have not change anything since last many days.. It was working earlier.

Comment: When I did echo $CLASSPATH it shows nothing.. What should I do now?

Comment: If I have wrong version of axis jars then how come it was working earlier? I have changed nothing then also it is showing errors.

Comment: @Advait: I am not sure what happened, but for sure I can say it is either jars missing in classpath (or) wrong version of jars in classpath. Check your classpath, that helps you in trouble shooting.